# Проблема со входом в админку сайта на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, login

есть странная проблема:

Сайт на Wordpress 5.8.1 (php 5.6.40).
При попытке зайти в админку штатным способом (по адресу http://******.ru/wp-admin) вместо показа страницы логина браузер предлагает СКАЧАТЬ страницу wp-login.php.

Такая проблема наблюдается во всех доступных браузерах (последние Хром, ФФ и т.п.), КРОМЕ IE11 (штатный браузер Windows 8.1). Но в осле работать невозможно, всё глючит и виснет.

Гугл выдает ответы не по теме. Подскажите, плиз, куда копать?

Comment: Неправильно настроен сервер. Никакой браузер не поможет. Пишите хостеру, или тому, кто управляет вашим серевером.

Comment: А остальное все работает? "При попытке зайти в админку штатным способом", а нештатным что? ))

Comment: Помогла Опера. В ней тоже нормально.
"штатным способом" означает без хакерства =)

Answer (score -3):

причин может быть много
1 взлом
2 повысте версию пхп

решения --- удалить сайт и БД
поставить туда чистый -- проверка на хорошесть хостинга

далее закинуть чистое ядро ВП на сайт http://******.ru/ обращать внимание на ССЛ или не СЛЛ есть различия у хостеров
смотреть в плагины и темы

Comment: Чепуха написана. Ни один пункт не имеет отношения к проблеме.